# Datadog unique occurences by one tag and creating pie chart on another tag

Tags: datadog, statsd

I have a counter metric in datadog with tags of id and type. There could be multiple occurrences of a particular id, and a specific id always has the same type. I want to get the unique id occurrences and create a pie chart by type tag.

E.g., if the occurrences are:
id    type
1      a
1      a
1      a
2      a
2      a
3      b
3      b
4      b
4      b

So the counter would have 9 occurrences.
I want to get a pie chart that says 2 for a (instead of 5 because there are 2 ids of type a ) and 2 for b (instead of 4 because there are 2 ids of type b )  without showing the id tag.

I know I can use:
a) clamp max(1) by id, type. But that creates a pie chart based on both id, type tags.
b) count_non_null by id, type but can't see the type tag anymore after using the function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.